# How to fetch data by user from google datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdoql, google-cloud-datastore

I am playing with google app engine and having a bit of trouble on [JDOQL queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html).

The example shows how to fetch stuff from the datastore:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
String query = "select from " + Greeting.class.getName();
List<Greeting> greetings = (List<Greeting>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
```

But what if I want to fetch stuff only for a given user?

At the bottom of the page in the link above it shows we could something like:

```
select from guestbook.Greeting where author == 'alfred@example.com'
```

But if I try the following it doesn't fetch anything:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
String query = "select from " + Greeting.class.getName() + " where author == '" + user.GetEmail() + "'";
List<Greeting> greetings = (List<Greeting>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
```

where `user` is fetched as shown in the same example like this:

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
```

i am sure this is a common task but I just can't get it to work - any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a discussion on [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/41fa419692cf1bea?pli=1) on Google Groups I got it working like this:

```
String select_query = "select from " + Greeting.class.getName(); 
Query query = pm.newQuery(select_query); 
query.setFilter("author == paramAuthor"); 
query.declareParameters("java.lang.String paramAuthor"); 
greetings = (List<Greeting>) query.execute(user);
```

JDQL syntax is puzzling ...

Comment: +1. no response... what do you expect for a Sunday?... a Sunny Sunday at that!

Comment: given the subject and the weather I couldn't really expect any  response :)